# Formik with react-bootstrap styling

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I am trying to use Formik with my react app.

I have react-bootstrap and I am trying to figure out how to style form components with bootstrap styling.

My form is:

```
// Render Prop
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import { Badge, Button, Col, Feedback, FormControl, FormGroup, FormLabel, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const style1 = {
    width: '60%',
    margin: 'auto'
}

const style2 = {
    paddingTop: '2em',
}

const style3 = {
    marginRight: '2em'
}

class Basic extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    firstName: '',
                    lastName: '',
                    email: '',
                    role: '',
                    password: '',
                    confirmPassword: '',
                    consent: false
                }}
                validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                    firstName: Yup.string()
                        .required('First Name is required'),
                    lastName: Yup.string()
                        .required('Last Name is required'),
                    email: Yup.string()
                        .email('Email is invalid')
                        .required('Email is required'),
                    role: Yup.string()
                        .required('It will help us get started if we know a little about your background'),    
                    password: Yup.string()
                        .min(6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters')
                        .required('Password is required'),
                    confirmPassword:  Yup.string()
                        .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
                        .required('Confirm Password is required')
                })}

                onSubmit={fields => {
                    alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(fields, null, 4))
                }}
                render={({ errors, status, touched }) => (

                    <Form style={style1}>
                    <h1 style={style2}>Get Started</h1>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                            <Field name="firstName" type="text" className={'form-control' + (errors.firstName && touched.firstName ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="firstName" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                            <Field name="lastName" type="text" className={'form-control' + (errors.lastName && touched.lastName ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="lastName" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                            <Field name="email" type="text" placeholder="Please use your work email address" className={'form-control' + (errors.email && touched.email ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="role">Which role best describes yours?</label>
                            <Field name="role" type="text"  placeholder="eg, academic, industry R&D, policy, funder" className={'form-control' + (errors.role && touched.role ? ' is-invalid' : '')} >
                            </Field>
                            <ErrorMessage name="role" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                            <Field name="password" type="password" className={'form-control' + (errors.password && touched.password ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="password" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                            <Field name="confirmPassword" type="password" className={'form-control' + (errors.confirmPassword && touched.confirmPassword ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="confirmPassword" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                        <Field component="select" name="color">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Field>
                            <Field name="consent" label="You must accept the  and Privacy Policy"  type="checkbox" className={'form-control' + (errors.consent && touched.consent ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                            <ErrorMessage name="consent" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                        </div>


                        <div className="form-group">
                            <Button variant="outline-primary" type="submit" style={style3}>Register</Button>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default Basic;
```

When I try to add a react-bootstrap form group to the  inside the render method, such as:

```
  <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
      We'll never share your email with anyone else.
    </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>
```

I get an error that says:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Formik`.

I think this error message is referring to element type to mean 'email' -- but it doesn't make any sense because the formik form i have already has an 'email' type in it and there is not error when I don't try to use react-bootstrap.

Has anyone figured out how to get Formik to work with react-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong `Form`. Import it from `react-bootstrap` instead of `formik` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this question about 5 years later with the same problem. How I solved it was to use React Bootstrap class names for Formik components.

For example, in the Form component in React Bootstrap, the CSS of the input field is handled by the class `form-control`. If you add this class to the `<Field>` component in your Formik form, it will work flawlessly.